# How to read data in text file from nth line to last

Tags: linux

I have a .txt file in Linux that have multiple lines.

Ex:-

line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6

And i want to read data from 4th line to end the file and need to copy to a separte .txt file.

Data should be like this in separate .txt file.

line 4
line 5
line 6

Answer (score 0):

using sed:

```
sed -n '4,$p' file.txt  >  other.txt
```

using awk:

```
awk 'NR>=4' file.txt > other.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

tail --lines=+4 file.txt > otherfile.txt